# php sessions to authenticate user on login form error: on localhost work properly but not on server

Tags: php

I have problem in login page after uploading the application on server, whilst it works properly on localhost. I didn't understand why it not working on IPAGE server, anything goes currently and application connect to mysql database, but when I enter the username and password, I got the user name and password error and not goes to main page.

This is the codes on login page:

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password= md5($_POST['password']);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE User_Name = '".$username."' AND User_Password = '".$password."' ");

    $result= mysql_num_rows($query);
    if ($result !=0)
    {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            $dbusername =$row ['User_Name'];
            $dbpassword = $row ['User_Password'];
            $_SESSION['user-id']=$row ['User_ID'];
            $_SESSION['User_UserA_ID']=$row ['User_UserA_ID'];
            $_SESSION['User_UserT_ID']=$row ['User_UserT_ID'];
        }
        // check to see if they match
        if ($username = $dbusername && $password =md5( $dbpassword))
        {
            header('location: main.php');
            $_SESSION['username'] = $dbusername ;
        }
    }
    //else die("User not exist!");
    else
    ?>
    <script>alert("Your User Name and Password is Wrong!!!"); </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Check the **$result** return by MySQL query

Comment: Oh and better use the mysqli_ functions. And never use $_POST values directly in database requests. And please use bcrypt instead of md5 ;-) And put a die; or exit; after your header redirect.